# How many ways are there to distribute eight different toys among four children if the first child gets at least two toys?

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions, multinomial-coefficients

My work:

$e_1 + e_2 + e_3 + e_4 = 8$

let $e_1\geq2$

with no constraint on the other $e_i$'s

we want to find coefficient of $\cfrac{x^8}{8!}$

with this I've found the exponential generating function to be

$g(x) = (\cfrac{x^2}{2!} + \cfrac{x^3}{3!}+...)(1 +x+\cfrac{x^2}{2!}+...)^3 = (e^{x}-1-x)(e^x)^3 = e^{4x}-e^{3x}-xe^{3x}$

so first series would be $ \sum_{r=0}^{\infty} 4^r\cfrac{x^r}{r!}$ for $e^{4x}$

Second series would be -$ \sum_{r=0}^{\infty} 3^r\cfrac{x^r}{r!}$ for $-e^{3x}$

But I get stuck here

What would the third series be for $-xe^{3x}$?

I need to figure this third series out to figure out the coefficient

Any help would be appreciated here.

Also is my logic and methodology right for this question?

If it helps, I just need help with the $-x$ in front of $-xe^{3x}$

It's really throwing me off as I'm not sure how it would turn into a series.

Comment: @lulu wouldn't that be if toys are identical?  Toys are different here I thought.  Instead, let us just look at the set of all such ways of distributing the toys and remove the "bad" results where no toys were given to the first child and where exactly one toy got given to the first child.

Comment: @JMoravitz Yes, my error.  I will delete my prior, unhelpful, comment now and this one soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find the coefficient of $\frac{x^k}{k!}$ in $x e^{3x}$, I find it easier to find the coefficient of $x^k$ and then multiply by $k!$.

The coefficient of $x^k$ in $x e^{3x}$ is the coefficient of $x^{k-1}$ in $e^{3x}$, which is $\frac{3^{k-1}}{(k-1)!}$. So the coefficient of $\frac{x^k}{k!}$ is $k! \cdot \frac{3^{k-1}}{(k-1)!} = k 3^{k-1}$.

Therefore our final answer should be $4^k - 3^k - k 3^{k-1}$, where $k=8$ in your case. That's $4^8 - 3^8 - 8 \cdot 3^7 = 41\,479$, which I also checked by brute force:

```
Length@Select[Tuples[Range[4], 8], Count[#, 1] >= 2 &]
```

gives $41\,479$ in Mathematica.

Answer (score 0):

kludginess says hello

I don't know enough about generating functions to specifically
examine your work.  However, I do know that there is a strong
relationship between generating functions and stars and bars
analysis.  Stars and bars is discussed at https://brilliant.org/wiki/integer-equations-star-and-bars/.

I also know that stars and bars analysis, at least in its
simplified form, is **inappropriate** here, specifically
because the toys are deemed to be **different**.

The problem is actually ambiguous, depending on whether the second, third,
and fourth child must each get at least one toy.

$\underline{\textbf{Interpretation 1: Some children may get no toys}}$

This is easy.

$$4^8 - \left(8 \times 3^7\right) - 3^8.$$

$\underline{\textbf{Interpretation 2: Each child gets at least 1 toy}}$

There may be an elegant approach here that I am unaware of.  My kludgy approach
is to identify all of the possible *satisfying toy distribution* **patterns** and then
enumerate each pattern.

Patterns:

P-1 : 5 - 1 - 1 - 1 : # ways $= S_1$.

P-2 : 4 - 2 - 1 - 1 : # ways $= S_2$.

P-3 : 3 - 3 - 1 - 1 : # ways $= S_3$.

P-4 : 3 - 2 - 2 - 1 : # ways $= S_4$.

P-5 : 2 - 2 - 2 - 2 : # ways $= S_5$.

The final tally will be $S_1 + S_2 + S_3 + S_4 + S_5.$

P-1
1st child gets 5 toys, other 3 toys are permuted. 
$$S_1 = \binom{8}{5} \times 3!.$$

P-2
Three ways of selecting which other child gets more than one toy. 
Then, you examine the # of ways that 1st child gets 4 toys, and other child gets 2 toys. 
Then, you multiply by 2, since the first child can switch roles with the other child here.

$$S_2 = 2 \times 3 \times \binom{8}{4} \times \binom{4}{2} \times 2!.$$

P-3
Analysis very similar to analysis of P-2. 
However, since the first child and the odd man out child
will each get 3 toys, you must not apply the factor of 2,
which would correspond to their switching places.

$$S_3 = 3 \times \binom{8}{3} \times \binom{5}{3} \times 2!.$$

P-4
If the first child is to get three toys, with one of the children the odd man out,
then the first tally is

$$ S_{4a} = 3 \times \binom{8}{3} \times 5 \times \binom{4}{2}.$$

If the first child is to get two toys, then there are 3! ways of deciding which
of the other children get 3 toys, 2 toys, 1 toy.

With this decided:

$$ S_{4b} = 3! \times \binom{8}{2} \times \binom{6}{3} \times 3.$$

$$ S_4 = S_{4a} + S_{4b}.$$

P-5
The # of ways of first giving 2 toys to 1st child, then giving 2 toys to 2nd child, ...

$$ S_5 = \binom{8}{2} \times \binom{6}{2} \times \binom{4}{2}.$$

Comment: I'm 100% sure that the problem is interpretation one. While I do appreciate the effort and I did find the same answer as you. I wish to learn how to solve this via exponential generating functions as that's what I am currently studying. But thank you for your effort!

Comment: @BadwaterBarry You must take this comment with a **large** grain of salt, since I am **totally ignorant** of the possible applications of generating functions.  My **very narrow** experience has been that generating functions are often a substitute for Stars and Bars analysis.  Since Stars and Bars is inappropriate here, this begs the question whether generating functions can be appropriately applied to interpretation 1 of this problem.  Note that the toys are deemed to be **different**.  It is almost as if you would have to *juggle* 8 variables: $x_1, x_2, \cdots, x_8.$

Comment: @user2661923 This is why we are using exponential generating functions rather than ordinary ones.

Comment: (By the way, if the second, third, and fourth child each need to get at least one toy, we'd be looking for the coefficient of $\frac{x^8}{8!}$ in $(e^x - 1 - x)(e^x - 1)^3$.)

Comment: @MishaLavrov Which *strongly suggests* that as the problem gets more complex, exponential generating functions **becomes** the superior approach.